# Missing System.Security.dll Assembly

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, cryptography, windows-phone-7.1, .net-assembly

I was trying to use the System.Security.Cryptography namespace in my Windows Phone 7 project. Of course the "Protect" class wasn't available and I figured that I have to upgrade my 7 app to 7.1.

I did that and still I can't see the class on that namespace. Then I figured I have to reference the System.Security.dll assembly and then it might work. Thing is.. I can't find the assembly

I right-click on the project, select 'Add Reference' and then under the .NET tab there's nothing of the sorts.

Any help?

Comment: Actually type `System.Security` on your keyboard - although it looks like you can't type search you can, see if you can find it then. EDIT: This is in the .NET tab of references once it has fully loaded (you know this when you can sort the references by name)

Comment: @Lukehennerley - That didn't work at all.

Comment: I'm so sorry - was just a quick suggestion. The naked eye sometimes isn't enough to look at a whole host of references, someone in my office had this exact problem and I suggested the above and he found it...

Comment: Your comment came across a bit sharp - hence my sarcastic reply. Further from you reading your comment on the answer below I have a bit more depth to have a look into what your encountering at the moment.

Comment: @LukeHennerley - Nha your reply didn't sound sarcasting at all. But sorry if you took my comment as a bit sharp. No harm meant. Just have to point out that I'm trying to get this working on a Windows Phone App.. Not some Desktop/Form program.

Comment: I see that you looked in the plain microsoft framework folder - there should be something similar to that but for your windows phone application (I judge it's using silverlight?) `c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone71` something along those lines, do you have this folder? As I believe this is the collection of .DLL files that you can reference internally to the project.

Comment: @LukeHennerley - The folder does exist like you say, but for some reason System.Security.dll isn't there. Why would a project created from scratch have the 'Protect' class in the namespace but my upgraded projects doesn't? Might it work if I remove the namespace, rebuild the project, re-add the namespace?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19435/discussion-between-lukehennerley-and-deangrobler)

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure that its not there? I just checked my reference files in the .NET section and System.Security is definitely included as part of .NET 4.0. You can sort the assemblies by name (ascending or descending) or search as the comment on your original post suggests. If its not there, what version of the .NET framework and Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: I tried to add the System.Security.dll from here: C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Security.dll and when I select it is says that I can't reference it since it wasn't built using the windows phone runtime.

Comment: Ah well this is a different issue all together then it sounds like you won't have access to this dll because the architecture doesn't match.

Comment: I'm following this tut on how to encrypt data on a windows phone app: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh487164(v=vs.92).aspx Here they just suggest that you'r app should be version 7.1 and it should just work... Any thoughts?

Comment: My only thought would be that in that tutorial he is using Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone. Perhaps it comes bundled with slightly different version of .NET dlls that are meant for phone development. Also it says he is using Silverlight for Windows Phone which could make a difference as well.

Comment: I also, am using the Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone. Should have told you that little bit of info. Anyways, I tried doing a project from scratch and it picks up the 'Protect' class in the System.Security.Cryptography namespace. But in my app that I upgraded from 7 to 7.1 it doesn't work. Re-Writing the app starting with  7.1 from scratch is crazy and impossible.